# Why my simple Kotlin code quit with exit code - 0xc00000005

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I created a very simple kotlin helloworld file as below from IntelliJ-idea, when I run that file in IDE env, I got exit code **0xc0000005**.

```
fun main() {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println("helloworld")
}
```

However, if I change "**Thread.sleep(1000)=>Thread.sleep(100)**", it seems ok and return "helloworld" to me.

And I also tried Kotlinc to compile it without IDE, it seems "Thread.sleep(1000)" can work on that, I can get "helloword" after 1 second, so, I guess some setting in IntelljIDE on that, maybe some timeout restriction.

Any Idea how I can let it run normally in IDE?

Comment: What OS and Java version/vendor/build do you use? This could be some antivirus related problem.

Comment: I am using win10 (x64), java 14, Intellij Idea 2023.3.2 (Community Edition). I don't have antivirus software (not sure windows defender counts)

Comment: Try with Java 11, 17 or 21 (the latest available builds) and see if it helps. See also if https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7997/0xc0000005-or-0xc000007b-crash-when-Mandatory-ASLR-is-tuned-on helps.

Comment: @BoxVery yes, windows defender counts, since that is the windows access violation error code. Try to run that code just once as administrator to see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks AlexT/CrazyCoder
, when I start by administrator account on Intellij-idea, it seems can work properly.

I don't expect to use administrator account on IDE for just such simple code to run.